# Increment value inside Jquery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code,

```
    $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  //dataType: "json",
  url: 'index.php',
  data : { lat : latValue, lng : lngValue },
  success: function (data){  
  console.log(data);

  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
  for(var k = 0; k <Object.keys(data).length; k++) {

   // zipcode_final[i][k] = ; 
   break;
}   
  }
  });
 //  csvRows.push(zipcode_final);
  }

});
```

See this edited code. How to get number of items ( length ) of data json object? This returns only number of characters. My Josn array looks like below,

```
[["44641","44730","44669"]]
```

Comment: Your code is not complete to figure out what's problem

Comment: The suggests you only loop once. Have you put some logging in to see what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have added some dummy code for you to figure out. Run the snippet. Check the values. I have commented line for zipcode_final as it wasn't defined.

```js
var str = '{"x":4,"y":5,"z":6}';
var data = $.parseJSON(str);
var k = 0;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  console.log('k = ', k, '; i = ', i, ';item = ', item);
  //zipcode_final[i][k] = item;
  k++
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: dj_coder please validate, is this what you were asking for?